# Option to not show edit in Active feed

Tags: feature-request

There are times when I need to update an answer with some minor changes and I would rather the "Active" feed not be updated with these changes. Can we have an option "Don't update Active feed" such that some people aren't disgruntled and call it "spam"?

Comment: Status-declined: [Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23241/270345), [CHAOS-like option for moderators to edit without bumping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131508/270345)

Comment: There is a way to view just newly posted questions though https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: @Seth yes that is how I did it when I first started. I just didn't want others bothered when I updated one of my own answers with code changes.

Answer (score 7):

If we allow users to hide their own edits, it would theoretically be possible for rogue users to start editing and vandalizing content behind-the-scenes in such a way that makes it impossible to detect and stop. Even assuming good intent, edits aren't always beneficial. They can introduce inaccuracies, further cause problems with the posts, or otherwise do Not Nice™ things.

Part of the moderation principle of this site is that users moderate themselves. This is why we have the review queues and (almost) everything is so transparent. Having a toggle to bypass this could be dangerous.

Similarly, bumping a question (by editing either the question or an answer to the question) is actually beneficial to the question. It attracts more attention (even if just for a fleeting moment) and allows more people to see it. See [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23242/259230) to a very similar question over on MetaSE.